# Screenshot that taken by iOS when (before) application go into background?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I hope that you all know about it, `iOS` takes screenshot before your application goes to background.

I got it from [official document.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW47)

> **Remove sensitive information from views before moving to the background:** When an app transitions to the background, the system takes a snapshot of the app’s main window, which it then presents briefly when transitioning your app back to the foreground. Before returning from your applicationDidEnterBackground: method, you should hide or obscure passwords and other sensitive personal information that might be captured as part of the snapshot.

So, Here We can hide our *"sensitive personal information"* and the system takes a snapshot of the app’s main window, so we can not change its feature.

But I want to know..

**1)** If in my application I'm at 4th View, and my app goes to background then system takes screen shot of which view/page? first one (start up view of apps?) or 4th view/page of the app ?? (here is little confusion for me).

**2)** Can we fire any action when system is taking screenshot or any notification is available that will inform us of system taking screenshot ??

**3)** I just want to know, is it possible to take screen shot *(programmatically)* before my application launch ?? If **YES** then give me suggestion for how to do it. And if **NO** then where/when I'm able to take screenshot *(I mean at which **minimum stage** of application we'll be able to take screenshot ?)* ?

Comment: which path on the device the one OS take screenshots are stored?

Answer (score 8):

1. It will take a screen short of the top most view, actually it is taking a screen shot of the window which is displaying your app.
2. No there is no notification that the screen shot is going to or being taken. You should just handle the handle it in the `applicationDidEnterBackground;` method. Just a stated in the documentation
3. No this is not possible, how do you want to execute any code before you app is running? The OS will make the screen shot, just be sure to have everything hidden in the  `applicationDidEnterBackground;`. The minimum state is that your app is up and running.

What I've done is on of my apps is as soon as my app gets pushed to the background place an extra view on my `UIWindow`. Thus when the screen shot is made this view is captured.

Comment: if i'm at 4th View and then my apps going to on background then system takes screen shot of 4th view ??

Comment: @3th Question - i mean which minimum stage/state of application that we able to take screenshot ?

Comment: Yes if you app get pushed to the background and you are on the 4th view then the screen will be made of the 4th view.But you will be able to push an new view on top and then the systeem will take the screen shot of that view. It will just the a screen shot of the last state of you app.

Comment: Thank you sir, just a little confusion, I am not sure but 95% `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method call first so it is beginning state of application  ? here can We able to take ScreenShot ?? But before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is it possible to take screenshot .. sorry for this type of silly question, but i want to improve my knowledge and also it is important for my application. may be you are understand, thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to when i am at 4th view and i press home button *(so basically my app. is in background)* and when i will press apps icon *(so basically my application will in foreGround)* a that time when my application will foreground then it will display specific viewController's view (may be 1st or 2nd ?) instead of 4th view of viewController ?

Comment: @iPatel, As rckoenes, suggested to add a view before app went to the background, you can create a `UIView` with the same view of your 1st or 2nd view (or whatever view you want to show). It could be the screenshot of that particular view which you've already taken before (if its static, then no need to take it every time). And you can assign that screenshot with that view, so at the time when the app goes into the background it'll take the screenshot of the view that you've just added with screenshots from 1st or 2nd view. I hope my big comment is understandable for you.

Answer (score 2):

1) There is just one screen. The screenshot is taken of that screen. In your model case that should be the 4th view controller's view. However, it is quite possible that your 4th controller's view does not cover all of the screen or has transparent elements. In that case parts of the 3rd or even 2nd and 1st view controller's view are part of the screen.

It is a screenshot not a view controller shot or anything.

2) You understood the documentation all right. The screenshot is taken after you returned from `applicationDidEnterBackground`. There will be no further dokumentation.

3) No, you cannot execute any code before your app is invoked. However, I have the feeling that you are looking for something different than you asked literally. 
For some other reason I have executed a small program in the simulator by implementing the main function only even without calling UIApplicatoinMain. This is the first point in time where code from your app may be executed, although that would not be exactly "out of the book". If I remember right, the screen was blank/black at that point in time. So if you are asking for a way of creating screenshots of other apps, this is not the way to go forward.

Comment: Thank you sir, just a little confusion, I am not sure but 95% `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method call first so it is beginning state of application  ? here can We able to take ScreenShot ?? But before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is it possible to take screenshot .. sorry for this type of silly question, but i want to improve my knowledge and also it is important for my application. may be you are understand, thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to when i am at 4th view and i press home button *(so basically my app. is in background)* and when i will press apps icon *(so basically my application will in foreGround)* a that time when my application will foreground then it will display specific viewController's view (may be 1st or 2nd ?) instead of 4th view of viewController ?

Comment: Frankly I don't know but that should not happen as along as the view of controller #4 is still visible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not taking a screenshot quite like a user pressing buttons.

This functionality is related to [state restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html). When the application goes to the background it flattens the view hierarchy for each screen into a screenshot used for the task manager. If you are opted into state restoration it will also persist the state of the user interface. This means that a person can bring the application back from the background state and potentially see sensitive information that way as well, which may be something you need to handle.

Preventing information from being included in the state screenshot is covered in [Tech QA 1838](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/QA1838/_index.html).

Answer (score -1):

1) I'm pretty sure the system will take the snapshot of the current visible view, so the last one on the stack, not the first one

2) Also, there will probably be a Notification to let us know that the system is going to take a screenshot (otherwise how can we hide sensible information? :) ), but I'm afraid we're currently under NDA I guess?

3) What do you mean "take screenshot before my application launch"? Your code starts executing when your application launches, so this question almost makes no sense :-/
You can anywhere in your application take a snapshot of the screen, however, and there are many stackoverflow posts for that

Comment: @vik.. at third answer i know that it is not possible to take screen shot before app. launch ,, and also know that we can anywhere in application take a snapshot of the screen. but i want to know about which  minimum stage of application that we able to take screenshot ??

Comment: Why would question 2 have any thing to do with a NDA?

Comment: I've probably misunderstood the 2nd question